# Proof Verification and Help: Showing a Map is Well-defined and a Bijection

Tags: functions, proof-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

Let R be the relation defined on the set of ordered pairs $Z_+ ×Z_+$
of positive integers defined by
$(a, b)R(c, d) ⇔ a + d = b + c$.
Prove that the function $f : Z_+ ×Z_+/R → Z$, defined by $f([a, b]) = a−b$, is well-defined and a bijection.

Proof: 
(For Well-defined function):
Let $(a,b)R(c,d)$

$\implies a+d = b+c$

$\implies a-b = c-d$ -----(1)

Since $(a,b)R(c,d) \implies [(a,b)]=[(c,d)]$

Now consider $f[(a,b)]$ and $ f[(c,d)]$

By definition, $f[(a,b)] = a-b $ and $ f[(c,d)] = c-d$

By (1), $\implies a-b = c-d$

Hence, the function is well-defined.

Proving Bijection:

1-1:

Let $f[(a,b)] = f[(c,d)]$

$\implies a-b = c-d$
$\implies a+d = b+c$

$\implies (a,b)R(c,d)$ $\implies [(a,b)]=[(c,d)]$

Hence, f is injective.

Can anyone please verify this? Also, I am unsure as to how to prove this is surjective, any hints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems to have the right ingredients, but it is poorly written, in my opinion.
Let just give a tide up version, and answer your last question.

You want to prove that $f$ is well defined.
It is clear that each element has an image, so your task is to prove that if $[(a,b)] = [(c,d)]$ then $f([(a,b)]) = f([(c,d)])$.
If $[(a,b)] = [(c,d)]$, then $(a,b)R(c,d)$, and so $a+d = b+c$; from here it follows that $a-b=c-d$, that is, $f([(a,b)]) = f([(c,d)])$.

To show it is injective, if $f([(a,b)]) = f([(c,d)])$, then $a-b=c-d$, whence $a+d=b+c$, yielding $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and $[(a,b)]=[(c,d)]$.

It is also surjective.
For $k \in \mathbb Z$, if $k \leq 0$, then $k = f([(1,1-k)])$ (notice that $1-k > 0$);
if $k > 0$, then $k=f([(k+1,1)])$.